# OL+Geoserver+PostGIS(postgreSQL)

Tags: openlayers-2

My task is to store the values in the database(postgreSQL) when the user inputs the lat-lon values in the form. and after submitting the form, the map should be displayed with markers at corresponding lat-lon values stored in DB. I have achieved this task using PHP,ajax & storing values in a text file. Now I have to do the same task using Geoserver+PostGis for which I am totally new. I have just installed Geoserver,postGIS,PostgreSQL in my system. I want your help to how to carry this task step by step. How to store these values in DB, how to retrieve them using geoserver.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wanna use google maps as my base map using OpenLayers.Layer.Google(sphericalMeracator: true).....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WFS-T is what you need. There are a lot of docs (http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Format/WFST/v1_1_0-js.html) and examples (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.8/examples/wfs-t.html)